# arjs - aframe | Working Devices & Webcams

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am using the simple arjs example to my angular project but i cannot get any  results using the hiro marker.

This is the code:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs>
    <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;'></a-box>
    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
</a-scene>
```

When I point my smartphone to a hiro marker nothing happens.

Is this because my device is not supporting AR? I have a Xiaomi redmi note 6 pro.

I read that in order for the AR to work on the device I need to have AR Google services which are not supported by my device.

> Does arjs need AR google services in order to work? If not what are
>   the other reasons?

PS.

1. I am on https and the camera is open.
2. **I am on an angular project and I am importing the scripts on the
       index.html head**

these are the scripts:

```
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Far As I Know `arjs` does not need `AR Google Services` in order to work

I think the problem is you need to put the your object, which is `<a-box>`, inside the `<a-marker>`

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!-- we import arjs version without NFT but with marker + location based support -->
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <a-scene embedded arjs>
            <a-marker preset="hiro">
                <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;'></a-box>
            </a-marker>
           <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also see another example here: https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/